# C function to read entire file not working

Tags: c

I wrote this small program to read an entire file into a `char*`, which I could then parse more freely than from a file. However, when I run it none of the file seems to get copied into `buf`, because neither printing the string or the individual chars seems to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("/home/<not shown>/.profile", "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    char *buf = malloc(ftell(fp) + 1);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while ((*buf++ = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {}
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

I'm pretty new to c, so could you help me find an answer to this conundrum?

Comment: `%s` requires the argument to be a null-terminated string. You need to replace the `EOF` at the end of `buf` with `'\0'`

Comment: You say that printing the string or the individual characters **seems to work**. If it works, what's the problem?

Comment: But when I do `while (...) { printf("%c\n", *buf); }`, It doesn't print anything (But the newline).

Comment: @Barmar Just a typo, but thanks for finding it.

Comment: After you're done incrementing `buf` to the end of the file, you no longer have the pointer to the beginning. You need to pass the original value of `buf` to `printf`. Also, check the return value from `fopen`, since it can and does fail, e.g. when the file doesn't exist.

Comment: You didn't check the result of `fopen`. Assume nothing!

Comment: When `fopen` fails, it seg faults. (Tested)

Comment: You didn't check the `malloc` either. Anyways, there is a nicer way of doing this, if you're using a *nix system, using `mmap`. Or `MapViewOfFile`, if you're using Windows.

Comment: `ftell()` is only guaranteed to count bytes for a binary stream. C11 draft standard: `7.21.9.4 The ftell function, Section 2 The ftell function obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream. For a binary stream, the value is the number of characters from the beginning of the file. For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information[...]`

Comment: @Majora320 when a program has several reasons it could segfault, you'll realise how necessary it is to check these things. For example, when instructor types in the wrong file name, it's an embarrassment to segfault, but polite to print "File not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're done with the loop, `buf` points to the end of the buffer, not the beginning. You should use a separate variable during the loop.

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
char *buf = malloc(ftell(fp) + 1);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
char *p = buf;
while (*p++ = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {}
// Replace EOF with null terminator          
*(p-1) = '\0';
```